# How to capture HTML5 data attribute when form is submitted to views.py of Django

Tags: python, django, html, attributes

As you can probably tell from the nature of my question, I'm a little new to this.  I have read similar post on this subject matter but most of it went right past my head and I did not feel like it was 100% applicable to the circumstance that I was facing so I thought I'd ask the question in a simplified way.

The question:

---

let's say I'm running the below HTMl form and a user submits the form to my views.py as shown in the views section below,  I would able to  store the value of the user selection by using: car_selection = request.POST.get('car')  .

My question is, how would I be able to capture the HTML5 data of  " data-animal-type="spider" " ?

I know there are Gurus out there but please do not explode my head. I would really need simplified help.

Thanks for helping.

---

Example HTML Form:

---

```
<select name="carlist" >
  option data-car-type="premium"  name= "car"  value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

---

---

Example Django View Function

---

```
def getcar(request):
    ... 
    if request.method == 'POST'
    ... 
    selected_carn = request.POST.get('car')
```

---

Comment: browser doesn't sends `data-car-type` to server - you can't get it in request. Browser can send only `name` and `value`.

Comment: an alternate method would be send the premium inside the value. So the value would have "{'type':'premium', 'val':'audi'}" and then on the server you can convert the string to a dictionary using json.loads(value)

Comment: Thanks Salmaan. This look good and really has me thinking .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it actually is possible. Say your view looks like this:

```
def getcar(request):
    ... 
    if request.method == 'POST'
        myform = MyForm(request.POST)
        ...
```

`myform` includes uncleaned form in html. The you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract data. Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
test = BeautifulSoup(str(myform))
data-values = [item["data-car-type"] for item in test.find_all() if "data-car-type" in item.attrs]
```

This will extract values from data-car-type attributes.

That being said, this does seem like a bad design. I surely would never go to such length to get the "car type" data. It's probably written somewhere in your database. Get it from there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason I want to obtain the data attribute value  from the submitted HTML5 data attribute is because  I will give the user a chance to increase the quantity of an item.  See like a shopping cart where you select two oranges or 4. As the user increases the quantity,  I will use jquery to increase the integer value of HTML5 data attribute. So in essence the data would be user-specified.  Is this plan bad?  Also, is it possible to not use Beautifulsoup. I am trying to have as little dependencies as possible so in the long run the solution is simple and compact.

Comment: I don't know how to put that increase of quantity into question's perspective and why would you like to put that value in the data attribute. If you put quantity in an input field or hidden input field inside form then it will be captured with `request.POST`. It's not a bad plan, it's just that the implementation with data attribute seems too complex or maybe I don't understand your plan entirely.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I know option 2  will work but I have not implemented option 1 before (trying now). Based on the short read-up I've done on beautifulsoup, I can see one little challenge that I have to deal with  but you have clearly provided a solution to the problem I presented to the community.  Thank you so much for giving your time.  Much appreciated.

Comment: looks like I'm not allowed to upvote because I'm a newbie with less than 15 points. Sorry : (

Comment: I'm glad it helped somewhat. No problem about the upvote. You can always open a new question related to quantities you have mentioned; with html, jQuery and views code and I'm sure we'll be able to find a better solution than this mess with data attributes and BeautifulSoup. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 4 year old but I came across this page when a similar question arose in my mind.

### Short answer

**It's not possible, unless your use Javascript on the front end side** as a workaround. The accepted answer is false.

### Explanation

Indeed, in the example above, try to `print(request.POST)` and you'll see that the `QueryDict` object `request.POST` received by the `view` does not contain any reference to the HTML5 data attribute you want to fetch. It's basically a kind of Python dictionary (with a few distinctive features, [cf. documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)). Admittedly, if you `print(myform)` in the same example, you'll see some HTML code. But, this code is generated retroactively, when you associate data with the form. Thus, BeautifulSoup will never be able to find what you're looking for. From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#the-view):

> If the form is submitted using a POST request, the view will [...] create a form instance and populate it with data from the
> request: `form = NameForm(request.POST)`. This is called “binding data to
> the form” (it is now a bound form).

### Workaround

What I've done on my side and what I would suggest you to do is to use some Javascript on the client side to add the missing information to the form when it's submitted. For instance, it could look like this:

```
document.querySelector("#form_id").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  const your_data_attribute = document.getElementById("XXX").dataset.yourInfo;
  const another_hidden_field = document.getElementById("YYY");
  another_hidden_field.value = your_data_attribute;
});
```